# Lucene, relevance/scoring for an in-memory string

Tags: lucene, full-text-search

I am building a bot that monitors HN for topics that I am interested in.

I'd like to analyze an in-memory string, and determine if it contains some keywords that I am interested in.

I'd like it to take into consideration the things that Lucene does when performing a standard query (word stemming, stop words, normalizing punctuation, etc).

I could probably build an in-memory index, and query it using the normal approach, but is there a way that I can use the internals of Lucene to avoid a needless index being built?

Bonus points if I can get a relevance value (0.0-1.0), instead of just a true/false value.

Pseudo code:

```cs
public static decimal IsRelevant(string keywords, string input)
{
   // Does the "input" variable look like it contains "keywords"?
}

IsRelevant("books", "I just bought a book, and I like it."); // matching!
IsRelevant("book", "I just bought many books!"); // matching!
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a solution using an in-memory search index. It's not ideal, but it does the task.

```cs
public static float RelevanceScore(string keyword, string input)
{
    var directory = new RAMDirectory();
    var analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48);

    using (var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, analyzer)))
    {
        var doc = new Document();
        doc.Add(new Field("input", input, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

        writer.AddDocument(doc);

        writer.Commit();
    }

    using (var reader = IndexReader.Open(directory))
    {
        var searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

        var parser = new QueryParser(LuceneVersion.LUCENE_48, "input", analyzer);
        var query = parser.Parse(keyword);

        var result = searcher.Search(query, null, 10);

        if (result.ScoreDocs.Length == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        var doc = result.ScoreDocs.Single();
        return doc.Score;
    }
}
```